# What does mk stand for in mklink also why does the first folder have to be removed?

Tags: windows, itunes, symbolic-link

I was just creating a directory junction and had to use mklink. My question is what does mk stand for in the word mklink? And why does the first folder have to be removed to create the link when doing something like `mklink /J "C:\Users\glenc\Apple\MobileSync\Backup" "E:\itunes-backups"`

I had to rename Backup as Backup2 so there wasn't a folder before I could use the mklink. At lease now I can finally have my Windows Store iTunes backup files on another HDD now.

Comment: MaKe Link, if a folder with the name you want to create a link to already exist you can't create a link with that name.

Answer (score 2):

`mklink` *creates* the file/folder `target`. It is not the same as `mount`ing a drive to a folder, you are creating an actual filesystem object that essentially says "go over there".

If the object being created already exists in a different form, whether a file or directory, then the existing object needs to be deleted in order to be allowed to be created.

"mk" is short for "make", as in "makelink". The same logic applies to `mkdir` and `rmdir` being "remove dir".